# a section invariant under Reeb flow

Tags: vector-bundles, contact-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact contact manifold with $R$ the Reeb vector field. Let $E$ be some vector bundle of gauge group $G$, say, $G = SU(2)$ and $E$ is the adjoint vector bundle.

So my question is:

If $\sigma$ is a global section, can I perform a gauge transformation (select a new trivialization) such that the transformed $\sigma$ satisfies $\mathcal{L}_R \sigma = 0$? To me the answer should be positive, since I can always adjust the basis so that the condition is satisfied, but I'm not sure.

Edit: Here $\mathcal{L}_R \sigma = 0$ is understood as $\mathcal{L}_R\sigma_i = 0$ where $\sigma = \sigma_i e_i$ with $e_i$ a local basis in every trivializing patch. $\mathcal{L}_R \sigma = 0$ is not a geometric relation, but more like a gauge-fixing condition.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\mathcal{L}_R\sigma $ ? Do you choose a connection on $E$ ? Also note that the Reeb field is defined only after you choose a contact form on $M$.

Comment: By $\mathcal{L}_R \sigma = $ I mean the $\mathcal{L} sigma_i = 0$ ,where $\sigma = \sigma_i e_i$ and $e_i$ is local basis for the vector bundle (So $R$ does not act on the basis $e_i$). It's not a coordinate-independent description, more like a "gauge choice". So I should rephrase as: can I choose local basis, such that all coefficients are invariant under $\mathcal{L}_R$? And to me it is very possible to achieve that, but I'm not sure.